# Change header size and image on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

I was kindly helped out with this issue but am having some more problems.

I'm wanting my header to change height when the user scrolls and with a smooth transition.

Currently it seems to be working but the content is being clipped when the height is adjusted on the nav, even though I have `overflow:visible` on the nav.

Secondly the animation seems to come in as soon as you scroll, even a little, whereas I want it to start when scrolled past 100px.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thXDt/)

```
$(function(){
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();

    if ( value > 100 ){
        $("nav").animate({height:100},"slow");

    }
    else{
       $("nav").animate({height:45},"slow");
    }
});
});
```

I also want the image to reduce to 80% of the size at present with a smooth transition.

Comment: An animation will come in as soon as you scroll because you have said if the scroll is not more than 100 animate the nav to be a height of 45

Comment: What is the effect you're looking to get?

Comment: @GaryRyan I am looking for a smooth animation where the header size reduces (and other contents will also need to change CSS) based on scroll. So entire header becomes smaller when scrolled past 100px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As informed by Luc, jQuery automatically sets `overflow: hidden` to `height/width` elements in animation.  To prevent the `overflow: hidden` from occurring, you can download the latest version of **jQuery** from **http://jquery.com/download/** and select the ***uncompressed version*** (**http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js**).  Comment out line `9123 //style.overflow = "hidden"`.  Save the file as a Javascript file and include this in your header as an external script file.  ***Make sure to remove jQuery reference***.

Additionally, I would suggest adding `.stop()` and change `"slow"` to a number you find suitable.

Here is the JSFiddle with jQuery and modifications:  [**>>>CLICK HERE<<<**](http://jsfiddle.net/thXDt/10/)

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var navIsBig = true;
    var $nav = $('nav');

$(document).scroll( function() {
   var value = $(this).scrollTop();

  if ( value > 100 && navIsBig ){
      $nav.stop().animate({
           height:45
      },1000);
      navIsBig = false;
  } else if (value <= 100 && !navIsBig ) {
      $nav.stop().animate({
          height:100,
      },1000);
      navIsBig = true;
  }
 });
 });
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. Now I just need to look into adjusting the CSS for the nav li links when the bar is small...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is: each time you're using the scrollbar, each time your function is triggered. So..

If scrollTop is for example equal to 80 and you go to 120. the function will be triggered 40 times and so you gonna call the animate function 40 times. Actually what you're doing is working but very very slowly due to this problem.

The Solution: you should use a boolean to verify what's the status of your nav tag.

if value > 100 and navIsBig then animate to 45
else if value <= 100 and !navIsBig then animate to 100

Second tip: Each time you're doing $('nav'), each time jQuery will go find nav in the DOM. just do it once and save it.

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thXDt/8/

```
$(function(){
  var navIsBig = true;
  var $nav = $('nav');

 $(document).scroll( function() {
   var value = $(this).scrollTop();

   if ( value > 100 && navIsBig ){
      $nav.animate({height:45},"slow");
      navIsBig = false;

   } else if (value <= 100 && !navIsBig ) {
      $nav.animate({height:100},"slow");
      navIsBig = true;
  }
 });
});
```

About the overflow: visible; Bad news for you, jQuery will force it to overflow: hidden; during the animation. You will have to do it in another way. Like using your logo outside the nav tag and play with css.

Comment: click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thXDt/8/) for an addition to Luc's answer that takes into account the text too.